# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when trying to create a new NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, exc-bad-access

I'm having troubles with creating `NSDictionaries` in a loop and adding it to an `NSMutableArray`.

Basically I just want to change the names of the keys, but since I couldn't find a function for that I went for following code:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)getCategoriesForChannel:(int)channelId {
    NSDictionary *data = [self call:@"get_categories.ashx"];
    NSArray *categories = [data objectForKey:@"categories"];
    NSMutableArray *returnArray = [NSMutableArray
                          arrayWithCapacity:[categories count]];

    for(NSDictionary *category in categories) {
        [returnArray addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         [category objectForKey:@"Channel_id"], @"id",
                         [category objectForKey:@"Channel_name"], "@name", nil]];
    }
    return returnArray;
}
```

But app always quits when it reaches the `addObject:` method and throws an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. I think that it has got something to do with memory management, but since I don't really have a C-background I have no idea how to solve this issue.
Can someone please point me to the right direction?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
[returnArray addObject:
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    [category objectForKey:@"Channel_id"], @"id",
    [category objectForKey:@"Channel_name"], "@name", nil]];
```

If this is in fact the code you have (and the typo wasn't introduced while writing it in your web browser), notice that the last key you have is `"@name"` instead of `@"name"`. That would effectively be a C-string, rather than an `NSString`, which can't properly be added into an `NSArray` (or most collection classes, for that matter).

Comment: Thank you sir, that was in fact the problem!

Comment: Sometimes another set of eyes is all you need! This saved me what I'm sure would have been hours of frustration. Thanks.

Comment: Arg, just made the same mistake ;-( unbelivable there is no compilation warning ....

Comment: Oh God. This seems to be a very common stuff - faced it and was frustrated with myself!! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Within the loop can you NSLog this [category objectForKey:@"Channel_id"] and [category objectForKey:@"Channel_name"]? I suspect one is giving nil and causing the trouble. Not sure. Just a guess.